# How to create One-to-many relationship in Entity Framework 4.1 using Code First and Data Annotations?

Tags: data-annotations, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I'm struggling with creating a simple one-to-many relationship using Code First in EF. I want it to generate daatabase for me but couldn't figure out how to write these classes so it would create it.

I have these classes:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{   [Key]
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    public  Book Book { get; set; }

    public string OtherField { get; set; }
}
```

But I get error while it ties to generate database:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'MvcApplication1.Models.Page' and 'MvcApplication1.Models.Book'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations

I just want to generate two simple tables, "Book" with ID as primary key, and Page with BookID as a primary and foreign key. It really should be simple but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But that is not one-to-many relationship. That is one-to-one relation ship which says that each book has exactly one page. The error says that it cannot determine if the book or the page is principal in the one-to-one relation.

You must modify your entities like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{   
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public string OtherField { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can also add virtual modifier to Pages and Book properties so that You get lazy loading.

Comment: but it generates Pages table that has primary key `ID` and foreign key `BookID`. How can I make it that it will generate only `BookId` that is primary key **and** foreign key.

Comment: You can't because in such case it will be one-to-one relation. Primary key can appear only once in the table - the value must be unique and foreign key must have the same value as related parent entity = if you want to model books with only one page you want this but if you want to model books with many pages you cannot have bookId as primary key in the page.

Comment: Of course you're right. I don't know what I was thinking... I'm too tired I guess.

Comment: What if you want to add a page while doing business logic ?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, In my case I have a simple 1-to-many (Contact-Address). I get and exception that I must specify the relationship explicitly. I tried adding `[ForeignKey("Contact")]` on `Address.Contact` property metadata, but I get a new exception: `System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Contact_Address_Target' in relationship 'Contact_Address'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'`. Any clue how to solve this?